# Use Linear Optimization from Google Apps Scripts in iOS?

Tags: google-apps-script

Is there a way to run the linear optimization code from google apps scripts in xcode?  I figured out way to run the example code and return the results to xcode but manipulating the variables in google scripts seems impossible...I want to be able to change the variables in the code in google scripts to variables from xcode...is this possible??

Comment: No not completely

Answer (score 0):

You can try to import [Glop](https://github.com/google/or-tools/tree/master/src/glop), Google's open-source [linear programming](https://developers.google.com/optimization/lp) system library.
" It's fast, memory efficient, and numerically stable."

I think it has the same linear programming concepts used in GAS although this is more appropriate for your situation since you're using this for a native iOS app. GAS is ideal for the web AFAIK.

An overview on how to use this is indicated in the [Running or-tools Programs](https://developers.google.com/optimization/run_programs#overview) guide. You can check how the examples are implemented to have an idea for your iOS implementation.

Comment: I have read about that. However, the guided are very vague and there is no information on using it in objective-c. I have done lenghty google searches and no examples either.